# how to deserialize one to many relationship with both eager sides without ending up in infinite deserialization loop

Tags: java, json, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jackson-databind

here is my Product class

```
@Entity
public class Product {

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="listingGroup_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    public ListingGroup listingGroup;
```

and here is my groupProduct class

```
@Entity
public class GroupProduct {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "listingGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
    Set<Product> products;
```

***GAOL***:

1. When I query for product, I want product with ProductGroup
   (ProductGroup should not serialize again the products inside)
2. When I query GroupProduct, I want the products inside (without these list of products each including again the GroupProduct)

***ALREADY TRIED***

1. JsonBackReference, JsonManagedReference:

   The GroupProduct get everything fine, but

   Problem : the deserialized products does not contain the group
   Product : {id: 1, ... groupProduct: null}
2. JsonIdentityInfo : I am not able anymore to deserialize the objects
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type...

***Environment***

- spring boot 1.5.8
- hibernate 5.0.12
- 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.8.0'
- 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.7'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [@JsonIgnoreProperties](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) annotation, like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("products")
public ListingGroup listingGroup;
```

or like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("listingGroup")
Set<Product> products;
```

or both.