# Spring Data JPA @OneToMany

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am designing the model of a DB:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_urna")
public class Urna implements Serializable {


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "urna", 
               cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
               orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Vot> vots = new HashSet<>();

..
}


@Entity
@Table(name="t_vot")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Vot implements Serializable {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "urna_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    Urna urna;

}
```

and I was wondering if setting FetchType.EAGER in both classes could cause a problem, like an ever ending loop or some stackoverflow.... and if it is a good practice

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49531769) should help...

Comment: You will not have a loop problem. But the EAGER fetch is a [code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/). I don't recommend to use it in any circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not have a neverending loop.

I don't think there is good or bad practices at this level. Sometimes it is better to use LAZY, because it prevent you from loading objects you don't need. Sometimes it is better to use EAGER, as it will prevent hibernate from running multiple requests if you need the objects.

When programming microservices, I always use EAGER (et bounded context aggregate). For a monolith, maybe LAZY is wiser.

Answer (score 0):

Default fetch type for `@ManyToOne` is `EAGER` anyway. If you set it on the `@OneToMany` it shouldn't end up with stack overflow.

If it is a good practice? I wouldn't say yes, but there are times when you need to fetch also related entities. But I would say it's always better to specify [entity graph](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/)